# Menu and Button Design in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to implement a menu with images as buttons. My main problem is, how do I set the text dynamically (I'm using language selection in my app) to the button? From what I've read I can set a background to a button but my images are not squared, and if I use ImageButton I can't write on the button.

My idea was to have a menu with buttons shown as below:

[image: menu pre selection]

And after clicked the menu would slide:

[image: menu pot selection]

Any ideas on how to achieve this? And how can I do it for all the phone resolutions? Thanks.

Comment: Most likely, you will need to create a custom `View` or two for this, where you draw the arc, lines, text, on-click highlights, etc. via the 2D graphics APIs (e.g., using the `Canvas`).

Comment: However I wanted to do this through high resolution .png's. I think drawing 2D graphics would be much slower. Is there any other way to achieve this (or something similar)?

Comment: "However I wanted to do this through high resolution .png's." -- which you can draw on the screen at the appropriate points using the `Canvas`.

Comment: I think I'll try that approach then. Any idea regarding the Locale? And is there a way to set up button listeners on the drawed .png's ?